# How to change the background color of xaml page in wp7 application?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, background-color

I am developing window phone 7 application. I am new to the window phone 7 application. I want to change the background color of the entire xaml page in the window phone 7 application. I have tried the following code in the constructor of the xaml page

```
 this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
```

But it is not working.

I have also added the attribute in the phone:PhoneApplicationPage tag as follows

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
Background="Red"
```

But it is also not working. Can you please provide me any code or link or any solution through which I can resolve the above issue? If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the Background property of the outermost control on the page. For a default page created in WP7 that would be a Grid named Layout.

You need to change the background of the LayoutRoot if you want to see the effect:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="YellowGreen">
..
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the theme does not respect the background color in the page. What you can do is add A border as a child of the page and set its background color to whatever you want.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage> 
<Border Background="Red">
...more content here...
</Border>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some options to set background of a page or grid.

suppose your xaml page is like below

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">  
  //start from here page design
</Grid>
```

1. If you want to set page from xaml then use following code. There are some options to set background of a page or grid

   ```
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">  
     //start from here page design
   </Grid>
   ```
2. If want to set from .cs file use below code at constructor `InitializeComponent();` methods which initialize page.

   ```
   public MainPge()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
   }
   ```
3. For all pages add following code at **app.xaml.cs** (tested only WP8.1 silverlight)

   ```
   public PhoneApplicationFrame RootFrame { get; private set; }
   public App()
   {
      ..............

      RootFrame = new TransitionFrame
      { 
         Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF))
      };
   }
   ```